# When are we going to be a full version SE site?

Tags: discussion

It seems like Database Administrators has become rather popular, and I'm just curious as to the point where we stop being "beta" and start being a full version of Stack Exchange site?

Comment: [Soon](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/329/what-will-happen-when-we-launch-aka-omg-what-happened-to-my-privileges).

Comment: Have you missed every other recent post on meta lately? ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Now.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/new-design-launched)

Answer (score 2):

See

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/

and

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/