# DBA SE graphic design: Who did it, and what else have they done?

Tags: discussion, design, theme

I've always enjoyed the graphic design of the DBA SE header:

[image]

Who made it and what else have they done? I like it and want to see more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The designer was [Jin Yang](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/100/jin) (user link):

See [Our Designer in Residence: Jin Yang](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/02/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) on the SO blog.

Related dba.meta Q & A:

- [Design for Database Administrators](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313/design-for-database-administrators)
- [New Design Launched](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/new-design-launched)